# How is the 5th iteration skipped?

Tags: javascript

How is the 5 being skipped, if it consist the `continue` then when 5 occure the loop will continue till the end

```
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  {  if(i==5){continue;}//how this works}

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `continue` starts a new iteration (thus skipping the `5` and continuing with `6`); `break` would jump out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong understanding of what `continue` does. I suggest to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue):

> The `continue` statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.